# Are maps into a smooth curve equivalent to relative effective Cartier divisors?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, divisors

Let $X$ be a smooth curve and $S$ an affine scheme, both over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Given a morphism $f : S \to X$, is it true that the graph morphism $\Gamma_f : S \to X \times S$ is a relative effective Cartier divisor for the projection $X \times S \to S$?

If the above is true, are all relative effective Cartier divisors of $X \times S \to S$ which do not contain any ``vertical fiber'' linear combination of graphs of morphisms $S \to X$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes for the first question, because $\Gamma_f$ is the preimage of the diagonal
$$
\Delta_X \subset X \times X
$$
under the map $1_X \times f \colon X \times S \to X \times X$.

No for the second question, because if $\Gamma \subset X \times S$ is the graph of a map $S \to X$ then the projection $\Gamma \to S$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the first question : I see that the diagonal should be an effective Cartier divisor but I'm not sure how to show this implies the preimage is also?

Regarding the second question : I know that divisors containing vertical fibers don't work. Excluding these, I asked whether all relative effective Cartier divisors of the projection can be written as linear combinations of graphs, rather than being of the form of a graph so I'm not sure how graphs being isomorphic to their source answers my question?

Comment: @user577413 (1) an effective Cartier divisor is a closed subscheme that is locally principal; a condition that is clearly preserved under pullback (inverse image). (2) The counterexample is any irreducible 'horizontal' divisor that does *not* project isomorphically onto its image in $S$. For instance, the parabola $y = x^2$ in $\mathbf A^2 = \mathbf A^1 \times \mathbf A^1$ does not project isomorphically onto the $y$-axis.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn (2) Ah I see! Thank you for the counter example. (1) Doesn't effective Cartier divisor need to be closed and locally defined by zero of a non-zero-divisor? I see that since $X \times X$ is integral, all local functions are non-zero-divisors. But how do I see that for general affine $S$, the restriction of local functions on $X \times X$ to $X \times S$ remains a non-zero-divisor?

Comment: You are asking why $\Gamma$ does not contain an irreducible component of $X \times S$? Just because every irreducible component has the form $X \times S_i$, where $S_i$ is an irreducible component of $S$, while the projection $\Gamma \to S$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Sasha I see that by going local, we can assume $X$ is affine. Then assuming $X \times S$ is reduced, a function on $X \times S$ is a zero-divisor iff it vanishes on some irreducible component and hence your argument goes through. However, $X \times S$ is not in general reduced right? (E.g. $S = \mathrm{Spec}\,k[t] / (t^2)$.) I'm also not sure how we can reduce to the case of $X \times S$ being reduced...

Comment: By your assumption $X \times S$ is smooth over $S$, hence tale locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1 \times S$. So, we can assume that function are just polynomials in one variable over functions on $S$. Therefore, if such a function $f$ is a zero divisor, there is a function $g$ on $S$ such that $fg = 0$ (this is an exercise in Atiyah-Macdonald).

Comment: @Sasha I'm not sure I follow. I only know $X \times S \to S$ smooth gives local étale coordinates. For example, taking $S = \mathrm{Spec}\,k$ and $X = \mathbb{G}_m$ I'm not sure I see how to give an étale cover of $\mathbb{G}_m$ by $\mathbb{A}^1$... Nonetheless I think I found an answer : I can use https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/067R to get the graph as a regular immersion, then use https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05D5 to show that we locally only need a regular sequence of length 1, i.e. a single non-zero-divisor, to define the graph.

Comment: I am not saying there is an etale cover, I just say that every point in $X$ has an etale neighborhood isomorphic to an etale neigborhood of a point in $\mathbb{A}^1$. In the example of $X = \mathbb{G}_m$ this is obvious.